# how to create real-time collaborative (multi-user) text editor in ajax

Tags: ajax, text-editor

I have to to create an Ajax based live text editor. The specifications are following;

• User logs in on the website

• User sees the list of logged in users

• User selects one of the logged in users let’s say B, if the user B is available (not communicating with any other user), it gets a connection request. If user B accepts the request, both users are connected.

• Once the users are connected, they share text editor. If user A enters anything on the text editor available on his screen, the same text is made visible on user B’s screen at the same coordinates. Similarly, if user B enters anything or removes anything from the text editor on his screen, the same happens on user A’s screen.

• Create pointer shaped images on both user’s screens to represent mouse pointers. When user A moves his mouse pointer, the image on user B’s screen should be moved according to the movement of user A’s mouse and similarly, when user B moves his mouse, the image on user A’s screen should be moved accordingly.

Can anybody help me??

Comment: What have you done so far? This is rather a project than a question!

Comment: I have done the first three parts. The sharing text on screens but mouse movement remains a problem. I couldnt get the coordinates of mouse using database as number of requests become to many that server crashes. Please help me out in mouse movement!!

Comment: How often are you recording the mouse movements, and sending them back to the sever to be inserted into the database? Every second, 5 seconds?

Comment: thts the point...actually i dont wanna use database for the mouse movement, it will give jerky effect. i wanna use some fast and efficient method.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use ASP.NET take a look at [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki). Its a JavaScript/C# library that allows you to easily broadcast to and invoke JavaScript on multiple web clients. You can literally accomplish a lot of what you want to do pretty easily and without a database.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use Node js socket connection for achieving real time collaboration.

Editor event can be available for current mouse position. Previous element sibling event can be used for finding where the users has inserted his content exactly.
 This need to be transferred to the other user and populate the data on his editor at the exact position rather than replacing his content.

Comment: Could you be more specific and provide some starting point example?

Comment: Sure!! Iam not sure whether this is the perfect solution but i achieved real time collaboration using node js socket connection. Please refer how can we achieve socket connection and transfer using socket io. I have used tinymce editor. Write a keyup/keydown event for tinymce. Inside that we can easily get the current working node ,previous element sibling and next element . pass these data as an object to the other user using socket io. Based on the data populate the text in the other user's editor.